# Elastic search merging sort and range functions

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch. currently i am working on sort and range functions in elastic search. My requirement is to sort the matching (who belong to accounts department) employees on the basis of height and whose height range should be in between 150 mm and 180mm.
Here is my query:

```
{


"query": { "match": {"department" : "accounts"} },
  "sort" : {
    "height" : {
      "range" : {
        "gte": "150",
        "lte": "180"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

But here i am getting SearchPhaseExecutionException.
Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filtered functions as follows:

```
{
"sort":{"height": "asc"},
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": { "match": {"department" : "accounts"} },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "height": {
            "gte": 150,
            "lte": 180
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```